# Sony Vaio Suddenly Shuts down

Tags: bsod, shutdown, sony-vaio

I have [Sony Vaio VPCF12S1E](http://www.sony.co.uk/product/vaio-f-series/vpcf12s1e-b) and it is 3 years old at the moment.

I have two major problems: a black screen and a blue screen. I opened my laptop and cleaned up parts really carefully. I changed the thermal paste and run stress tests: CPU heated up to 75 degrees and GPU up to 57 degrees under 100% load. There were no shutdowns during tests. So I don't think the BSOD and KSOD are related to heat.

Blue screen occurs randomly when I use the laptop. On a regular usage, the screen freezes but sounds keep playing and I can use keyboard to send commands (for example I can send my voice over TeamSpeak or receive others'). After a few seconds of freeze, I get the blue screen.

As for the black screen, again during a normal usage, the screen shuts down but processes keep executing for a few more seconds (like maybe 2 secs) and the power abruptly goes down.

What is it's problem? Anybody can help me? Please ask for further details, if you need any.

Comment: Enter into your BIOS and keep the machine as it is, check whether the machine shutdown or not. you said you get a blank screen.Is it after booting to OS or before it?

Comment: if your computer is running at 75 C on idle, thats a pretty damn big problem, check your task manager and see if the CPU is constantly at 100% activity. your computer on idle should be running at 30-35 degrees C Max.

Comment: Sickest, 75 C at %100 activity. On Idle it is between 40-44 degrees C Max. @RenjuChandran when i go back to my home i will check it after enter into my BIOS and i will tell you result

Comment: The question is updated as OP asked. Please see the updated question for more proper info about the problem

Comment: By the way @renjuChandran black screen question is yes after OS it shuts down suddenly.

Comment: This computer already passed this Stress-test successfully. ( prime95 - Burnintest )